# How should I call a Dialogflow CX Messenger script from Google Tag Manager?

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-tag-manager, messenger, dialogflow-cx

I have setup my Dialogflow CX and Messenger on my web site and I want to execute commands with Google Tag manager.

Basically what I want to do is that if a user scrolls more than 75% of a page, vertically, GTM should trigger this example ( taken from https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration/dialogflow-messenger#rendercustomcard )

```
    const dfMessenger = document.querySelector('df-messenger');
const payload = [
  {
    "type": "info",
    "title": "Info item title",
    "subtitle": "Info item subtitle",
    "image": {
      "src": {
        "rawUrl": "https://example.com/images/logo.png"
      }
    },
    "actionLink": "https://example.com"
  }];
dfMessenger.renderCustomCard(payload);
```

This code snippet works fine if I embed it in my web page, and also in when GTM triggers and embeds the tag after a scroll the snippet. But when I try the other types of cards, List type is what I would like to use in my case, I the following in my browsers console "DfMessenger: Could not render undefined".

Any clue if this is due to me triggering things from GTM or any ideas what I could test?

Comment: I figured out what was wrong with const dfMessenger = document.querySelector('df-messenger')
         dfMessenger.addEventListener('df-request-sent', function (event) {
             console.log(event) and compared with the objects and found a misspelled wording. Everything works but you have to be really careful with spelling. I still think the documentation is a bit poor though, but that is not for this forum.

Comment: please post the answer in the Answer section here in Stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Posting this answer from @Per Olsson as a wikianswer:

I figured out what was wrong with const dfMessenger = document.querySelector('df-messenger') dfMessenger.addEventListener('df-request-sent', function (event) { console.log(event) and compared with the objects and found a misspelled wording. Everything works but you have to be really careful with spelling. I still think the documentation is a bit poor though, but that is not for this forum.